# QGIS-modeler: How to name a column of a point layer from a raster

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, column

I have several rasters named after the date and time (e.g. YYMMDDHHMM: 2107152050I) and a points layer. I want to extract the values from each raster to each of the points and therefore I created a simple model in QGIS 3.16 (tool: sample raster values).

For each iteration, a column is added and the output file is used for the next iteration. I want to name the new columns with the name of the related rasters.

I tried with a simple string `file_name('Raster1')`, but it does not work. Any suggestion?

[image]